# Mayer-Vietoris for a cover without triple intersections

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $M = \bigcup_i U_i$ be a cover with open sets $U_i$ such that for 
for distinct $i,j,k$ we always have $U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k = \emptyset$.

I would like to show the existence of the following exact sequence

$$\rightarrow \bigoplus_{i < j} H_q(U_i \cap U_j) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i} H_q(U_i) \rightarrow H_q (M) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i < j} H_{q-1}(U_i \cap U_j) \rightarrow$$

using only the Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms and without using CW-approximation.

For a finite cover I thought one could somehow induce on the Mayer-Vietoris
but I failed.

I heard that for generic covers (without the tripel intersection property) there is a spectral sequence allowing to compute the homology of $M$ with the homology of the $U_i$. Sadly I don't know
spectral sequences and so I am hoping for a proof without them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this in the book Bott, Tu "Differential forms in algebraic topology". Section 8 "Generalized Mayer-Vietoris principle" is exactly what you are asking about.

They actually implicitely do use spectral sequences, but they don't call it this way, and the explanation is very clear and elementary.