# Inverse mapping of a contractible space

Tags: algebraic-topology

So, let us be given a nonconstant continuous function $f:X \to Y$ and $B\subset Y$ is contractible. Now, I wonder if $f^{-1}(B)$ is contractible.

I need this to solve a problem correctly(if you can do whole problem, better for me anyway) which states: Let A,B,C be open and contractible subsets of $RP^2$, such that $A \bigcup B \bigcup C = RP^2$. Show that $A\bigcap B \bigcap C$ is nonempty. I need to solve this in terms of algebraic topology(no wonder if some :see this image, then contract this, glue that and join this,this and that, can solve this, I do not care of that solution), so I try to do something by considering a covering space of $RP^2$ is $S^2$, and using $p: RP^2 \to S^2$ is a continuous function.

But, unless that what I have stated in the first paragraph was true, I am sitting ducks and have no idea how to solve this correctly(I mean I can not be like my friend who said: Oh, $RP^2$ is a quotient of $D^2$ but that is not true).

Comment: (1) I think you want to look at $S^2 \to RP^2$. I don't know what map goes the other way. (2) $RP^2$ _is_ a quotient of $D^2$. Just identify antipodal points on the boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Take the constant function $f:S^2\to\{0\}$, where $S^2$ is the $2$-sphere (or any non-contractible space).

Comment: That is true, but does not serve my needs. thanks for your answer. I meant this in general case.

Answer (score 1):

Spenser has already given you an example why the preimage of a contractible subspace need not be contractible.  To help build intuition about why it's absurd to expect this, here are more examples with nonconstant maps.  Take $Y = \mathbb{R}^n$, $X$ to be any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f$ to be the inclusion of $X$ in $Y$.  If the preimage of $B = Y = \mathbb{R}^n$ were contractible, this would mean $X$ is contractible.  But there are many subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - this includes all manifolds, for example - many of which are not contractible.

Now, for your other problem.  I would try to apply Mayer-Vietoris to the given cover.  You'll probably need the "[generalized Mayer-Vietoris principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540404/50427)" (also see Bott-Tu), which is really just the Mayer-Vietoris SS.  In this case, if you suppose $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$, I think you'll find that $$H_1 \mathbb{R}P^2 = 0,$$ which is a contradiction.  My calculation might be a bit off, so you should really double-check, but I think the Mayer-Vietoris sequence will be helpful here working with unions and intersections of easily understood open subsets.