# Is there a Mayer-Vietoris sequence for an (uncountably) infinite collection of sets?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

In Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, Van Kampen's theorem is stated for a (possibly uncountably infinite) collection of path-connected open sets $A_\alpha$ whose union is some topological space $X$.

Mayer-Vietoris sequences however, which are the analog for homology of Van Kampen's theorem for the fundamental group, are only stated to exist for pairs of subspaces $A, B \subset X$, such that $X$ is the union of the interiors of $A$ and $B$.

To be precise, I was wondering whether for a collection of subspaces $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$, such that $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in I} A_\alpha = X$, there exists an exact sequence
$$\dots\longrightarrow H_n(\cap_{\alpha\in I} A_\alpha)\longrightarrow \oplus_{\alpha\in I} H_n(A_\alpha)\longrightarrow H_n(X)\longrightarrow H_{n-1}(\cap_{\alpha\in I} A_\alpha)\longrightarrow\dots$$

given an uncountable or countably infinite index set $I$.

Comment: It is more complicated than you expect.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2769742/mayer-vietoris-type-theorem-for-complex-divided-into-more-than-two-parts?rq=1